# Remove brackets from NSMutableString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a NSMutableString like this:

```
(
    993,
    12836,
    10630
)
```

how can i remove brackets?

EDIT

the string is the result of this instruction:

```
NSMutableString * result = [labelpost description];
```

Comment: Is it really a string? Is this from a log of an array? `substringWithRange:`...

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: from log it looks like an array instance.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have code that is dependant on the output of `description`. What happens when/if Apple changes the output from `description`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the `description` method as the format of the output it gives you is not guaranteed.

Instead, use a specific method on the object, like for an `NSArray` instance, use `componentsJoinedByString:` to create your desired string output.

Comment: While I agree and never use the `description` method, Apple (at least unofficially) is backing away from the "do not use in code" stance. I suspect that there is so much such usage they can't afford breaking apps that use it. Still: just don't do it.

Comment: The point is that they could change it as they have never promised that they won't. This also applies to the many `NSStringFrom...` functions... @Zaph

Comment: Note that I am not disagreeing and think it is a really bad practice to use the description method in production code. But I disagree with not using the `NSStringFrom...` functions, I see no caveats that these are just for debug. There are noted usages on some but not all. Again on some there is explicit documentation on the form.

Comment: i'm using you solution, but if i want to Log only "993", how can i do it?

Comment: @Zaph, true enough, for the ones where there is a corresponding function to return from a string.

Comment: Extract only the object at the first index and log it. Remember that how you log and how you convert to string values for future use in code are 2 different things...

Comment: i'm trying with this "NSLog([labelpost objectAtIndex:0]);" but it doesnt work :(

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [labelpost objectAtIndex:0]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's NSString you can remove it by call:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like labelpost is an array. The method description generates a string that describes the contents of the object. In the case of an array, you get an open paren, then a comma-separated list of objects, then a closing bracket.

As the other poster, Greg, said, you can use stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString to convert your parens to empty strings, but then you will be left with

> ```
> 993,
> 12836,
> 10630
> ```

(With a blank line at the top containing a single space, newlines after every line, commas, and a space after the last object, and a final blank line.)

If that's what you want, fine. What is your final goal?

Try logging the class of labelpost and its contents:

```
NSLog(@"label post class = %@", [labelpost class]);
if ( [labelpost isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] )
{
  NSArray *array = (NSArray *)labelpost; //Cast labelpost to an array
  for (id anObject in array)
    NSlog(@"Object class = %@, object = %@", [anObject class] [anObject description]);
}
```